# Can I use parametric and non-parametric tests in the same publication?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, manova, vegan

I have a rather difficult dataset. One measurement is non-normal and zero-inflated and could not be transformed to normality. Thus, a `glm` was used. Another set of measurements requires a multivariate approach. I tried a `MANOVA` but the data is non-multivariate normal (confirmed with `mshapiro.test()` from the `mvnormtest` package) and I cannot achieve normality with any transformation. I also cannot find a solid answer on how to perform a `multivariate glm` in R. Thus, I believe I am left with the non-parametric `adonis` function from the `vegan` package (for permutational manovas). So my question is, is it a *faux pas* to include a parametric test (glm) and a non-parametric test (permanova) in the same publication for a single dataset?

Not sure if this will help but here are the outputs of `adonis` and `Anova(manova)` of the same dataset. Significance follows same the trend.

```
> adonis
Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

adonis2(formula = data[, 4:ncol(data)] ~ Sample * Treatment, data = data, permutations = 999)
                 Df SumOfSqs      F Pr(>F)    
Sample            4  0.21326 4.1826  0.001 ***
Treatment         4  0.13082 2.5658  0.003 ** 
Sample:Treatment 16  0.34364 1.6850  0.005 ** 
Residual         50  0.63733                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


> Anova(manova)

Type II MANOVA Tests: Pillai test statistic
                 Df test stat approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)    
Sample            4    2.8008   3.6704     84    132 1.209e-11 ***
Treatment         4    2.7037   3.2775     84    132 5.071e-10 ***
Sample:Treatment 16    7.2608   1.7804    336    720 9.870e-11 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Welcome to CV, J.Con. This is an interesting question. Why not simply go completely nonparametric? (Are you hurting for power in your data set?) Leaving editorial policy aside, I think the issue is *how compelling a narrative are you creating with mix-n-match methods vs a unified approach?*

Comment: @Alexis thank you for the reply. These may not be the best reasons, but reasons they are. 1. I spent a lot of time and effort figuring out the `glm` for the first part of the data. I was helped by a professor and am positive it is correct. 2. Two papers with VERY similar designs that are directly relatable to this study used glms and it is necessary that I emulate them for that part of the dataset. Cheers

Comment: I frequently see varied analyses presented. Often it is useful to see results from multiple analyses - helps to confirm findings or show that findings vary under certain conditions. Regarding MANOVA, it is very likely your analysis will be fine without normality assumption being confirmed - MANOVA is robust to violations of normality with larger samples except in cases with extreme outliers. If the sample is large enough, and did not have have extreme outliers, I would use MANOVA.

Comment: @Bryan thanks for the comment. There are 15 samples per treatment, no extreme outliers.

Comment: There is no reason to not match parametric and non parametric methods in a paper, if there is a reason for analyzing things in the respective ways. If you seem to randomly vary methods with no rationale given, then there might be a concern that you picked methods based on what results they give.

Comment: Another issue is that (frequentist) inference on a transformed variable ($y = f(x)$) is not valid inference on the *back-transformed* variable  ($x = f^{-1}(y)$), even if you back-transform the CI and.or *p*-values, because $\sigma^{2}\left(f(x)\right)\ne f\left(\sigma^{2}_{x}\right)$—the variance of a function of $x$ (other than the identity function) does not equal the function of the variance of $x$—which implies the same for the standard errors from which the CI and *p* value are calculated. Going fully nonparametric gets around this. 1/2

Comment: There are alternatives if you *realy* want to perform inference on back-transformed variables, like the Delta method, but that's a lot more work. 2/2